# Is it safe to have a dangling pointer?

Tags: rust, undefined-behavior

I have the following Rust code:

```rust
extern crate libc; // 0.2.66

use libc::{free, malloc};

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let mut p = malloc(16);
        let mut q = p;
        free(p);
        p = std::ptr::null_mut();
        q = std::ptr::null_mut();
    }
}
```

Is it undefined behavior to change `p` and `q` after the `free`, like in this code? In my real code, `q` would stay a dangling pointer for a long time until the cleanup code can run on it, but it doesn't get used during that time.

Comment: No, it is not UB. You freed `p` then re-assigned the variable a new, valid value. That's legitimate.

Comment: In fact, there is a perfectly safe [`NonNull::dangling()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/struct.NonNull.html#method.dangling) function in the standard library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rust's raw pointers on their own can never cause undefined behavior. Since this code only calls `malloc` and passes the value back to `free`, it could only be UB if those C functions defined that sequence of calls to be UB, which they do not.

Dangling pointers are not a problem — **dereferencing** dangling (or otherwise invalid) pointers is a problem. That doesn't happen here.

---

This is distinct from Rust's references, which are always guaranteed to refer to a valid value an may never dangle. This example **is undefined behavior**:

```
let mut p = malloc(16);
free(p);
&*p;
```

```
error: Miri evaluation error: dangling pointer was dereferenced
 --> src/main.rs:9:9
  |
9 |         &*p;
  |         ^^^ Miri evaluation error: dangling pointer was dereferenced
  |
  = note: inside call to `main` at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/rt.rs:67:34
  = note: inside call to closure at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/rt.rs:52:73
  = note: inside call to closure at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/sys_common/backtrace.rs:129:5
  = note: inside call to `std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::<[closure@DefId(1:6016 ~ std[49a3]::rt[0]::lang_start_internal[0]::{{closure}}[0]::{{closure}}[0]) 0:&dyn std::ops::Fn() -> i32 + std::marker::Sync + std::panic::RefUnwindSafe], i32>` at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/rt.rs:52:13
  = note: inside call to closure at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/panicking.rs:296:40
  = note: inside call to `std::panicking::r#try::do_call::<[closure@DefId(1:6015 ~ std[49a3]::rt[0]::lang_start_internal[0]::{{closure}}[0]) 0:&&dyn std::ops::Fn() -> i32 + std::marker::Sync + std::panic::RefUnwindSafe], i32>` at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/panicking.rs:272:13
  = note: inside call to `std::panicking::r#try::<i32, [closure@DefId(1:6015 ~ std[49a3]::rt[0]::lang_start_internal[0]::{{closure}}[0]) 0:&&dyn std::ops::Fn() -> i32 + std::marker::Sync + std::panic::RefUnwindSafe]>` at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/panic.rs:394:14
  = note: inside call to `std::panic::catch_unwind::<[closure@DefId(1:6015 ~ std[49a3]::rt[0]::lang_start_internal[0]::{{closure}}[0]) 0:&&dyn std::ops::Fn() -> i32 + std::marker::Sync + std::panic::RefUnwindSafe], i32>` at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/rt.rs:51:25
  = note: inside call to `std::rt::lang_start_internal` at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/rt.rs:67:5
  = note: inside call to `std::rt::lang_start::<()>`
```

As is this:

```
let mut p = malloc(16);
free(p);
p = std::ptr::null_mut();
&*p;
```

```
error: Miri evaluation error: invalid use of NULL pointer
  --> src/main.rs:10:9
   |
10 |         &*p;
   |         ^^^ Miri evaluation error: invalid use of NULL pointer
   |
   = note: inside call to `main` at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/rt.rs:67:34
   = note: inside call to closure at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/rt.rs:52:73
   = note: inside call to closure at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/sys_common/backtrace.rs:129:5
   = note: inside call to `std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::<[closure@DefId(1:6016 ~ std[49a3]::rt[0]::lang_start_internal[0]::{{closure}}[0]::{{closure}}[0]) 0:&dyn std::ops::Fn() -> i32 + std::marker::Sync + std::panic::RefUnwindSafe], i32>` at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/rt.rs:52:13
   = note: inside call to closure at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/panicking.rs:296:40
   = note: inside call to `std::panicking::r#try::do_call::<[closure@DefId(1:6015 ~ std[49a3]::rt[0]::lang_start_internal[0]::{{closure}}[0]) 0:&&dyn std::ops::Fn() -> i32 + std::marker::Sync + std::panic::RefUnwindSafe], i32>` at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/panicking.rs:272:13
   = note: inside call to `std::panicking::r#try::<i32, [closure@DefId(1:6015 ~ std[49a3]::rt[0]::lang_start_internal[0]::{{closure}}[0]) 0:&&dyn std::ops::Fn() -> i32 + std::marker::Sync + std::panic::RefUnwindSafe]>` at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/panic.rs:394:14
   = note: inside call to `std::panic::catch_unwind::<[closure@DefId(1:6015 ~ std[49a3]::rt[0]::lang_start_internal[0]::{{closure}}[0]) 0:&&dyn std::ops::Fn() -> i32 + std::marker::Sync + std::panic::RefUnwindSafe], i32>` at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/rt.rs:51:25
   = note: inside call to `std::rt::lang_start_internal` at /root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libstd/rt.rs:67:5
   = note: inside call to `std::rt::lang_start::<()>`
```